# Rendertron needs to run behind an HTTP proxy

Tags: rendertron

I have a scenario that [Rendertron](https://googlechrome.github.io/rendertron/) services need to run behind an HTTP proxy. I am not able to find the configuration that enables this setup.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no straight way to achieve it right now. What you can possible do is to change its source code until there is a new version of Rendertron that supports running it behind an HTTP proxy.

You can add an additional argument when launching the headless browser puppeteer as below, in [src/rendertron.ts](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/blob/master/src/rendertron.ts)

[image]

And when starting Rendertron, be sure to pass in the environment variable `RENDERTRON_HTTP_RPOXY`. See [this open GitHub pull request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/pull/373/commits/0c2060503171b7bf005c5a73895da77056502122) for details.

It is also possible to specify puppeteer arguments in config, see [another open GitHub pull request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron/pull/372/commits/4c645129b5b7af894a4df76ccc698ae2ac89e5cf).